# How can you export code when using a Mac?

Tags: macos, export, processing

I am a teacher trying to work through COVID distance learning with students who are learning Processing.

I am not a Mac user and I can't figure out how to help the students save their files (or export them) on their Macs so that they can share their code with me.

Screenshots would be very helpful so that I can share with them how to do this on a Mac.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I think the process is quite simple, just click "File" in the top menu and then select "Save" or "Save As ..."

[image]

Once they have saved the file, they just need to navigate to the folder using the finder and right click > compress the file. This process will generate a zip file that they can share with you via email.

[image]